# How to drop the rows if and only if values of particular columns are missing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, missing-data

I need to handle the missing values by dropping a particular row or column. I know how to drop a column or row with missing values, but what I need is a little bit different. I need to drop the rows if and only if two particular columns have missing values.

Here is the example I have tried:

```
# Basic libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'First':[100, 90, np.nan, np.nan], 
        'Second': [30, 45, 56, np.nan], 
        'Third':[np.nan, 40, 80, np.nan],
        'Forth': [30,40,50,np.nan]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df1.dropna(subset=['First','Second'],inplace=True)
df1
```

As shown, I am trying to drop the rows where `First==Nan` and `Second==Nan`. In other words, I need both conditions to be correct. So, I need just the last row to be dropped, **where both values are Nan.** So, row 2 will not be deleted since one of the conditions is satisfied. Unfortunately, the command I've used drops the rows if one of the conditions is satisfied.

Comment: pass `how="all"` to the `dropna` function.

Comment: @Swier I appreciate your help, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `how='all'` parameter in [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), for you not working because default value is `how='any'`:

> **how**: {'any', 'all'}, default 'any'
> Determine if row or column is removed from DataFrame, when we have at least one NA or all NA.
> 'any' : If any NA values are present, drop that row or column.
> **'all'** : If all values are NA, drop that row or column.

```
df1.dropna(subset=['First','Second'],inplace=True, how='all')
print (df1)
   First  Second  Third  Forth
0  100.0    30.0    NaN   30.0
1   90.0    45.0   40.0   40.0
2    NaN    56.0   80.0   50.0
```

EDIT: For pass variable list use:

```
list_columns = ['First','Second','Third','Forth']
df1.dropna(subset=list_columns,inplace=True, how='all')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked well, but what about passing a `list of columns` to the subset? i.e. 
`list_columns = ['First','Second','Third','Forth']

 df1.dropna(subset=[list_columns],inplace=True, how='all')
`

Comment: @QaddomiObaid - remove `[]` from `[list_columns]` and use `df1.dropna(subset=list_columns,inplace=True, how='all')`